# Не является приложением Win32

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

Такое дело, скомпилировал программу в на релиз x86 решил проверить на старом компьютере выводится сообщение "Не является приложением win32" когда компилировал под x86. Из сторонних библиотек подключил только `SFMLx86` из либов следующие

```
opengl32.lib
winmm.lib
gdi32.lib
freetype.lib
sfml-main.lib
jpeg.lib
sfml-graphics-s.lib
sfml-window-s.lib
sfml-system-s.lib
sfml-audio-s.lib
```

На моем компьютере все работает, даже пробовал вынести в отдельную папку. В чем дело?

Comment: Нет нужной версии Visual C++ Redistributable?

Comment: А ваша программа действительно является приложением win32 а не 64-битным?

Comment: >>на старом компьютере<< Вы, случайно, не под WinXP запустить пытаетесь?

Comment: Да, windows xp.

Comment: Программа действительно 32 битная

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664861/how-to-target-windows-xp-in-microsoft-visual-studio-c Убедитесь что у вас есть апдейт студии на билд для WinXP, и выберите его. Это общеизвестная проблема.

Comment: А минимальная версия системы у исполняемого файла какая?

Comment: У тулсета должен быть постфикс _xp. Тогда всё будет работать)

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: Если вы исправите свой вопрос, и добавите пояснения что делаете сборку в относительно современной msvs и запускаете её на Windows XP, он станет ещё более полезным для этого ресурса.

Comment: Теперь вот такой случай (на старом пк) https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpWTL.png

Comment: @Duoxx Это сообщение возникает при необработанном исключении. Войдите в отладку и посмотрите, что за исключение.

Comment: На основном компьютере (windows 10) никаких исключений нет

Comment: Проект собрался? Тогда вопрос можно считать решённым. Для отлавливания исключения используйте отладчик, либо создавайте другой вопрос с подробным описанием ситуации...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данная "проблема" появилась с первых версий MS Visual Studio 2012 (а так же, встречается во всех последующих версиях, 2013, 2015, 2017), и связана с отказом от поддержки устаревшего Windows XP. (Чем конкретно это обоснованно - неизвестно)

В то же время, в первый месяц компанию засыпали гневными отзывами о том что программисты больше не могут собирать свои проекты под данную операционную систему. Тогда же, компания выпустила обновление, которое отдельным набором инструментов для платформы позволяла собрать работающую программу под XP.

Зайдите в свойства проекта, и убедитесь что целевая платформа с постфиксом "_xp":
[image: Настройки]

По умолчанию, при установке студии 2012 (или старше), вам так же должны были предлагать установить обновление для компиляции под целевую платформу Windows XP

[image: Установка]

Если же вы проигнорировали этот пункт, есть возможность поставить обновление, которое добавит в вашу студию сборку под Windows XP.

---

[Ссылка на подобный вопрос на англоязычной версии stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664861/how-to-target-windows-xp-in-microsoft-visual-studio-c)